# What is the most recommended way for lightweight virtualization on Debian 8 Jessie?

Tags: linux, virtualization, docker, debian-jessie

When Debian 6 was launched, I used a virtualization tool called OpenVZ, when Debian 7 was launched, OpenVZ was deprecated and people were advised to use LXC instead.

On Debian 8, I saw Docker and LXC, coming from OpenVZ, what is the most recommended way for me to virtualize my machines? I've heard that Docker is an "application container" so that would be different from LXC? what about LXD?

Comment: What are your requirements?

Comment: I have LAMP machines virtualized via OpenVZ, every machine contains a lot of applications running on them. I only plan on virtualizing Debian on Debian.